# Return a new list of keys from a dictionary if items in a list is in that dictionary else return the item?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

Suppose I have a list and dictionary as below:

```
list1 = ['moscow', 'warsaw', 'kobe', 'eyywyeyw', np.nan]
my_dict = {'russia':['vladivostok','moscow'],
           'poland': ['krakow','warsaw'],
           'japan':['tokyo', 'kobe']
          }
```

How do I get this new list:

```
new_list = ['russua', 'poland', 'japan', 'eyywyew', np.nan]
```

I have tried:

```
for key, value in my_dict.items():
    for x in list1:
        if x is not np.nan:
            if x in value:
                new_list.append(key)
            else:
                new_list.append(x)
```

Comment: Did your solution work? If not how is it mis-behaving? Do you suspect any part of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this.

```
new_list=[]

for word in list1:
     for country,states in my_dict.items():
         if word in states:
             new_list.append(country)
             break
     else:
         new_list.append(word)
```

> *The else block just after for/while is executed only when the loop is NOT terminated by a break statement.*

---

output

```
['russia', 'poland', 'japan', 'eyywyeyw', nan]
```

Answer (score 2):

Make a *reverse* dictionary then use it to create a new list.

```
import numpy as np
D = {a:k for k,v in my_dict.items() for a in v}
r = [D.get(item,item) for item in list1]
```

---

Assumes all values are collections.

Comment: What a beautiful answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
for city in list1:
        changed = False
        for key in my_dict.keys():
            if city in my_dict[key]:
                new_list.append(key)
                changed = True
                continue
        if not changed:
            new_list.append(city)
```

Comment: can you explain the use of `change = True` and `change = False`?

Comment: Sure, i loop over every element in list1. If i find the element in the dictionary I add the Country to the new list and continue to the next item. If I looped through the whole dict and did not find the city changed will still be false (otherwise it'll be true) and I add the city to the new list, because it's country could not be found

Answer (score 1):

Assuming no overlap between city names, I would flip the dict and use a list comprehension for this.

```
flipped_dict = {v: k for k, vs in my_dict.items() for v in vs}
# {'vladivostok': 'russia',
#  'moscow': 'russia',
#  'krakow': 'poland',
#  'warsaw': 'poland',
#  'tokyo': 'japan',
#  'kobe': 'japan'}

list2 = [flipped_dict[i] if i in flipped_dict else i for i in list1]
print(list2)
# ['russia', 'poland', 'japan', 'eyywyeyw', nan]
```

Comment: Great approach and beautiful answer, but very similar to @wwii 's one

Comment: Yes, but I wrote mine first.

Comment: Oh okay, sorry. I thought he had responded first